# Does Rviz have collision detection like gazebo?

Tags: ros, gazebo, rviz, collision

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am wondering if rviz has a collision detection system similar to gazebo implemented. I see that there is an option to enable collision, but I have not found and information online about what it does exactly.

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
ROS: Indigo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237700/does-rviz-have-collision-detection-like-gazebo?/) by [justinkgoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27238/justinkgoh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2016-06-21

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rviz only renders data, so it does not have collision detection. The option you're seeing is to visualize the collision geometry, which can be different from the visual geometry. A common example is to have a high polygon and detailed mesh for visualization of your robot, but for collision detection you might just use a box or a sphere so it is faster. rviz can render these shapes, but does not do any collision detection with them.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2016-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [justinkgoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27238/justinkgoh/) on 2016-06-30**:
Thanks for the info.